# Problem with ANSI Encoding file with Encryption in Linux, Java

Tags: java, encryption, utf-8, ansi

I export a database  with mysqldump a database in Ubuntu with java, then I encrypt and decrypt it with Java. I doing that with the following classes [Encrypt and Decrypt with Java](https://github.com/raktotpal/MyInternal/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kogentix/internal/AESEncryption/). But after the decryption some characters at the start of the file is wrong. Here is the problem:
[image]
At the first image is the file which programmatically have mysqldump, encrypt and decrypt. At the second one is just the mysqldump from the same command line. Can you point me the direction what to do? Thanks

EDIT
I have create a salt and stored it in a file like this:

Encryption:

```
        FileInputStream saltFis = new FileInputStream("salt.enc");
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        saltFis.read(salt);
        saltFis.close();

        // reading the iv
        FileInputStream ivFis = new FileInputStream("iv.enc");
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        ivFis.read(iv);
        ivFis.close();

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(secretAlgorithm1);
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(rsaSecret.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), secretAlgorithm2);

        //
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithmEncryption);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        // file encryption
        byte[] input = new byte[64];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
            if (output != null)
                outFile.write(output);
        }

        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
        if (output != null)
            outFile.write(output);

        inFile.close();
        outFile.flush();
        outFile.close();
```

Decryption:

```
        FileInputStream saltFis = new FileInputStream("salt.enc");
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        saltFis.read(salt);
        saltFis.close();

        // reading the iv
        FileInputStream ivFis = new FileInputStream("iv.enc");
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        ivFis.read(iv);
        ivFis.close();

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(secretAlgorithm1);
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(rsaSecret.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, 256);
        SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), secretAlgorithm2);

        // file decryption
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithmEncryption);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(decodedB64);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] in = new byte[64];
        int read;
        while ((read = fis.read(in)) != -1) {
            byte[] output = cipher.update(in, 0, read);
            if (output != null)
                fos.write(output);
        }

        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
        if (output != null)
            fos.write(output);
        fis.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        System.out.println("File Decrypted.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that one is simple. That idiotic (but funny enough, seeming largely correct otherwise) method of file encryption using CBC stores the IV in a separate file, overwriting any old one. So if you overwrite or take the wrong IV file then you'll get 16 random bytes at the start after decryption. So unless you can find the IV file that hopefully makes sense, your first 16 bytes (/characters) are now lost forever.

Of course, any sane encryption program stores the salt (a password & PBKDF2 is used for key derivation) and IV in the same file as the ciphertext.

Still, if you managed to lose the salt file or password then all the data would have been lost, so there's that...

---

With the added code the issue becomes even more clear. In the encryption mode you are forgetting to create & use an `IvParameterSpec` entirely during initialization:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
```

however, because of the way the IV data is read, you don't get any warning that the variable isn't used:

```
ivFis.read(iv);
```

If you would have created a nice method such as `IvParameterSpec iv = readIvFromFile()` then you would have caught this error.

---

Note that Java (by default in the included provider for `Cipher`) uses an all zero IV, so you're lucky and your data isn't partially gone.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have created one time the salt and the iv so I don't have everytime new. But I am getting the same result.

Comment: @KostasC Amended answer. It was the IV. Such a hint should really have given you enough information to proceed with debugging.